# Android error: Nested signal detected - original signal being reported

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is killing me.  I'm new to android/Xamarin.  I can't find anything on the web that explains what is going on here.

I'm using xamarin forms for my application.  I have a page that synchronizes the device with a web service.

The method simply retrieves 100 records at a time from the web service and updates a sqlite table on the device.  I randomly get this error.  I'm running 5000 records for my test sample.

Here is the button click:

```
 public async void OnSyncCachedData_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        activityIndicatorAll.IsRunning = true;

        try
        {
            actIndSyncItems.IsRunning = true;
            SyncAllFinished += SynchAllFinishedProcessing;

            await Task.Run(async () => await App.ItemsRepo.LoadCacheDataFromCacheAsync(DbPath).ConfigureAwait(false));

        }
        catch (BAL.Exceptions.NetworkException nex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert(Messages.TitleError, nex.Message, Messages.MsgOk);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert(Messages.TitleError, string.Format(Messages.MsgAreYouConnectedParm1, ex.Message), Messages.MsgOk);
        }
        finally
        {
            EventHandler handler = SyncAllFinished;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            SyncAllFinished -= SynchAllFinishedProcessing;

        }

    }
```

the main worker method:

```
public async Task<bool> LoadCacheDataFromCacheAsync(string dbPath)
    {
        WebSvcManagers.ItemsManager itemsWebServiceManager = new WebSvcManagers.ItemsManager();
        List<Models.WebServiceItems> consumedRecords = new List<Models.WebServiceItems>() { };
        int bufferSize = 100;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "LoadCacheDataFromCacheAsync starting");
        try
        {
            {
                int lastID = 0;
                IEnumerable<Models.WebServiceItems> remoteRecords = await BAL.DataAccessHelper.GetItemsFromGPCacheAsync(App.Login, lastID, bufferSize, itemsWebServiceManager).ConfigureAwait(false);
                while (remoteRecords.Count() != 0)
                {
                    foreach (Models.WebServiceItems remoteItem in remoteRecords)
                    {

                        // DbActionTypes dbAction = (DbActionTypes)remoteItem.DbAction;
                        Models.Items itemRecord = new Models.Items() { ItemNumber = remoteItem.ItemNumber.ToUpper().Trim(), Description = remoteItem.Description.Trim() };
                        Log.Debug(TAG, "Processing {0}", remoteItem.ItemNumber.Trim());

                        bool success = await AddRecordAsync(itemRecord).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        if (success)
                            consumedRecords.Add(remoteItem);

                    }
                    lastID = remoteRecords.Max(r => r.RecordID) + 1;
                    remoteRecords = await BAL.DataAccessHelper.GetItemsFromGPCacheAsync(App.Login, lastID, bufferSize, itemsWebServiceManager).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

            }
           // await UpdateConsumedRecords(consumedRecords).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.StatusMessage = ex.Message;
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Error Catch: {0}", StatusMessage);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            itemsWebServiceManager = null;
            HandleSyncFinished(this, new EventArgs());
            SyncAllFinished -= HandleSyncFinished;
        }
    }
```

My simple webservice manager:

```
        public static async Task<IEnumerable<Models.WebServiceItems>> GetItemsFromGPCacheAsync(Models.Login login, int offset, int bufferCount, WebSvcManagers.ItemsManager manager)
    {
        try
        {
            return await manager.GetCacheRecordsAsync(login, offset, bufferCount).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And the code for the interaction with the web service:

```
const int bufferSize = 100;

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.WebServiceItems>> GetCacheRecordsAsync(Models.Login login, int offSet, int bufferCount)
    {
        string deviceID = App.ConfigSettings.DeviceID.ToString("D");
        try
        {
            ///* Testing start */
            //return await DataStore(bufferCount, offSet).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ///* Testing end */

            if (!App.IsConnected)
                throw new BAL.Exceptions.NetworkException(Messages.ExceptionNetworkConnection);

            string user = login.UserName;
            string password = login.Password;
            HttpClient client = HttpClientExtensions.CreateHttpClient(user, password);
            try
            {
                List<Models.WebServiceItems> items = new List<Models.WebServiceItems>() { };
                int lastID = offSet;
                int i = 0;
                string uri = string.Format("{0}", string.Format(Messages.WebRequestItemsCacheParms3, deviceID, lastID, Math.Min(bufferCount, bufferSize)));
                Log.Debug(TAG, string.Format("Webservice {0}", uri));
                string response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
                while (i < bufferCount && response != null && response != "[]")
                {
                    while (response != null && response != "[]")
                    {
                        dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

                        foreach (var item in array)
                        {
                            i++;
                            items.Add(new Models.WebServiceItems()
                            {
                                ItemNumber = item["ITEMNMBR"].Value.Trim(),
                                Description = item["ITEMDESC"].Value.Trim(),
                                DbAction = (int)(item["DbAction"].Value),
                                RecordID = (int)(item["DEX_ROW_ID"].Value),
                            });
                            lastID = (int)(item["DEX_ROW_ID"].Value);
                            Log.Debug(TAG, string.Format("Webservice {0}", item["ITEMNMBR"].Value.Trim()));
                        }
                        if (i < Math.Min(bufferCount, bufferSize))
                        {
                            uri = string.Format("{0}", string.Format(Messages.WebRequestItemsCacheParms3, deviceID, lastID + 1, Math.Min(bufferCount, bufferSize)));
                            Log.Debug(TAG, string.Format("Webservice {0}", uri));
                            response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Log.Debug(TAG, string.Format("Webservice return {0} items", items.Count()));
                return items;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Error Catch: {0}", ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException nex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format(Messages.ExceptionWebServiceLoginParm1, nex.Message));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I've had assistance from a Xamarin instructor and we thought we got it, (because this is random), but it clearly is not swatted.  I've been hitting my head up against a wall for over 3 weeks on this.  It smells like a memory leak, but I have no idea how to find it with such a generic error message that doesn't appear on web searches.

Somebody out there with some major brains,   Please help!

#### Error:

```
08-03 12:41:11.281 D/X:ItemsRepositiory(16980): UpdateRecordAsync 65702-40710 
08-03 12:41:11.306 D/X:ItemsManager(16980): Webservice DeleteCacheRecordAsync 20497 
08-03 12:41:11.406 D/X:ItemsManager(16980): Webservice api/InventoryItems?DeviceID=7c5bb45d-2ea0-45b9-ae50-92f2e25a2983&OffSet=20498&Ma‌​x=100&cached=true 
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7 08-03 12:41:11.521 E/art (16980): Nested signal detected - original signal being reported The thread 'Unknown' (0x7) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Where is that error msg reported? Are you catching it (i.e. is it a managed exception)? Logcat output? Does it crash the app, are you capturing the crash and symbolizing it? Can you post the entire message.

Comment: it busts right through the catch statements. I don't appear to be able to control the error at all.  Generally it just crashes the android app back to the home screen.

Comment: the error was from the output of VS during debugging, but it shows in the log as well

Comment: this is the log from VS:  08-03 12:41:11.281 D/X:ItemsRepositiory(16980): UpdateRecordAsync 65702-40710
08-03 12:41:11.306 D/X:ItemsManager(16980): Webservice  DeleteCacheRecordAsync 20497
08-03 12:41:11.406 D/X:ItemsManager(16980): Webservice api/InventoryItems?DeviceID=7c5bb45d-2ea0-45b9-ae50-92f2e25a2983&OffSet=20498&Max=100&cached=true
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
08-03 12:41:11.521 E/art     (16980): Nested signal detected - original signal being reported
The thread 'Unknown' (0x7) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a problem with the VS Android Emulator. As we have shown in tests, this is not reproducible on the Google Android Emulators, nor on Xamarin Android Player, nor on a physical Android device.

Comment: I would agree except I assumed the same thing and started using the device for the testing instead.  The problem is reproduce-able on the device, (granted, only while debugging so far).  I've run one test base on your advice and it was successful.  I'm hoping for grand results in the next hour.  Thanks!  as soon as I know, I'll up vote you.

Comment: Yup, works like a charm on the device in no debugging mode